# Not able to connect to Teradata using Python

Tags: python, teradata

```
import teradata
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="testconnec", version="1.0",logConsole=False) 
session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="TeraDev",username="usename", password="password");
```

> **above code is failing with error**: 
>   Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "", line 1, in    File
>   "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py",
>   line 183, in connect
>       **args))   File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py",
>   line 421, in **init**
>       init(odbcLibPath)   File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py",
>   line 366, in init
>       initOdbcLibrary(odbcLibPath)   File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py",
>   line 319, in initOdbcLibrary
>       odbc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(odbcLibPath)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 438, in LoadLibrary
>       return self._dlltype(name)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/**init**.py", line 360, in **init**
>       self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: libodbc.so: *cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`*

```
export ODBCINI=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/odbc.ini
export ODBCINST=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/odbcinst.ini
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib
```

***After adjusting above env variable****

```
import teradata



udaExec=teradata.UdaExec(odbcLibPath="/opt/teradata/client/16.20/odbc_64/lib/libodbc.so",appName="testconnec", version="1.0",logConsole=False)

session = udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="TeraDev",username="user", password="password", driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20");


Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 183, in connect
    **args))
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 454, in __init__
    checkStatus(rc, hDbc=self.hDbc, method="SQLDriverConnectW")
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 231, in checkStatus
    raise DatabaseError(i[2], u"[{}] {}".format(i[0], msg), i[0])
teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, u'[IM002] [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified')
```

Comment: So it can't find the ODBC Driver Manager. Did you install the prerequisite Teradata ODBC driver? Is the directory containing the driver in the search path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)?

Comment: please note, that package "teradata" is the unsupported, so I always recommend "teradatasql" instead - as well "teradata" leverages ODBC, while "teradatasql" has a native connection.

Comment: @Fred Do we need Teradata client installed as well ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Teradata client". As @hhoeck noted, the teradatasql package is preferred but requires 64-bit Python 3.4 or later.

Comment: @Fred we have installed the driver and we get this error when we try to connect: teradata.api.DatabaseError: (0, u'[IM002\u42fe\u7fdc] [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Driver Manager Message file not found. Please check for the value of InstallDir in your odbc.ini.'

Comment: At least it loaded the driver manager this time. Double-check your ODBCINST and ODBCINI to be sure they are correct. If you have more than one driver with the word "Teradata" in the name then append `,driver="Teradata"` (for 15.10 or earlier) or `,driver="Teradata Database ODBC Driver xx.yy"` (where xx.yy is the desired version, for 16.00 or later) to the connection string to ensure the correct driver is chosen.

Comment: @Fred thanks. I got a different error after correcting env variable [updated my question]

Comment: If *TeraDev* is your Teradata system (network) name, then the keyword should be `system="TeraDev"`. Or with `dsn="TeraDev"` you need a `[TeraDev]` section in your ODBCINI file to define the connection options (and likely don't need `driver=` after all).